# How to check a radio button with Selenium WebDriver Reading data from excel

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Coded UI for creating some test cases for a web application, while doing the same I have encountered an issue. I am not able to select a Radio Button using their Displayed Text, however if I use the ValueAttribute then its working fine. But, since value attribute is not containing a number which may not be of any logical use for a person creating test data, so I need to do same work using the Displayed Text of the Radio button.

Here is my html code

```
<td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_NewChanged" value="1131">
    <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_0">New</label></td>
    <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_NewChanged" value="1132">
    <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_1">Changed</label></td>
    <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_NewChanged" value="1133">
    <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_2">Longstanding</label></td>
```

I have tried the following code. but didn't work

```
 String selectType = data.getType().get(rowCnt);// data reading from excel stored to string variable
                List<WebElement> type = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < type.size(); i++) {
                    if (type.get(i).getText().equals(selectType)) {
                        type.get(i).click();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: String selectType = data.getType().get(rowCnt);//data reading from excel stored to string variable
   System.out.println("radio buttons" +data.getType().get(rowCnt));
   List<WebElement> type = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));
   System.out.println("type" +type);
   for (int i = 0; i < type.size(); i++) {
    if (type.get(i).getText().equals(selectType)) {
     type.get(i).click();
    
    }
   }

Comment: Update the question with the code.

Comment: @SreejithaJ Are you getting the `String` values e.g. _New_, _Changed_, _Longstanding_. etc from excel?

Comment: I am able to read data from excel , but cannot select a radio button using their displayed text, however if I use the ValueAttribute then its working fine.

Comment: To get the label of the radio button , you can use like this 
    List<WebElement> type = 
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']/../label"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the `String` values pertaining to the text of the `<label>` tags e.g. New, Changed, Longstanding. etc from excel then you can write a function which will acccept the texts as `String` as follows:

```
public void clickItem(String itemText)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//label[starts-with(@for,'ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_NewChanged_')][.='" + itemText + "']")).click();
}
```

Now you can call the function `clickItem()` by passing the `String` argument to click on the relevant *Radio Button* as follows:

```
String selectType = data.getType().get(rowCnt); // data reading from excel stored to string variable
clickItem(selectType); // will support clickItem("New"), clickItem("Changed") and clickItem("Longstanding")
```

**Note**: As per the *HTML* you have provided the `clickItem()` method should work with the implemented [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). As an alternative you can also replace the `clickItem()` function to click on the `<input>` node as follows:

```
public void clickItem(String itemText)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//label[.='" + itemText + "']//preceding::input[1]")).click();
}
```